# Edge shall not GET-preload functional URLs unless users click on them

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

In a web application, I use traditional HTML anchors such as `<a href="?id=123&action=delete&csrf=xyz">` as buttons to trigger functions. Delete a resource, for example.

Recently, users of the app report that just visiting the page with Edge on Windows 11 triggers such functions. Sounds like the browser tries to preload the "page" behind the URL, triggering an action although the user did not actively click.

On the web, I found information on a general DNS prefetching in Edge, but no on such page preloading. More so, I did not find a "plain HTML" way to tell the browser not to preload certain links. So my question is: Has anyone else experienced such behavior? And if that behavior occus, is there a way that won't require me to change all `<a>` into forms with `<button>` to prevent browsers from "preloading" action links?

Comment: Does this issue only occur in Microsoft Edge? How about this behavior in other browsers?

Comment: I have reports from only 2 of many users who report the issue, and when using a different browser, the issue does not occur. It also seems to be related to specific characters in the URL - as a `<a href="?id=file.MP4&action=delete">` is left alone, while `<a href="?id=file.mp4&action=delete">` (will mp4 instead MP4) is triggered automatically. I was not able to replicate the behavior myself, so this is a somewhat desperate call :)

Comment: Well, in the meanwhile I received notice from the other user ... they used Chrome on MacOS. So it seems not to be a generic Edge issue. Probably using hyperlinks to trigger actions is not such a good idea as I thougt it to be.

Comment: Yes, I think so. It would be better to use buttons to trigger actions/functions.

Comment: The problem occured for two users (of ~500 using the respective feature), but I got no further reports since. Might be a bug in certain browser versions or a problem caused by certain plugins ...

Answer (score 0):

give a try to use the rel="nofollow" attribute on your links and the following code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="?"]').forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any reference that rel="nofollow" relates to preloading? Also, it seems unwise to preventDefault() on all links, at first glance, if I want them to work as links.  Could you please elaborate on that a bit? Thank you.